# C++ Multiple template parameter packs in specialization

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-specialization

I am playing around with parameter packs and got some behaviour I was  not able to explain (in my understanding it should be valid).

I have a templated struct taking one type and a specialization using two parameter packs (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0cb6c6fef7b09e6f):

```
    #include <type_traits>
    template<class, int> struct dummy{};
    template<class...> struct multiple{};

    template<class T, class = std::true_type>
    struct exactly_one_not_0 : std::false_type {};

    template<class...LTs, class...RTs, class T, int V>
    struct exactly_one_not_0
    <
        multiple
        <
            dummy<LTs, 0>...,
            dummy<T, V>,
            dummy<RTs, 0>...
        >,
        std::bool_constant<V>
    > : std::true_type
    {};

    template<class T>
    constexpr bool exactly_one_not_0_v = exactly_one_not_0<T>::value;

    using d0 = dummy<int,0>;
    using d1 = dummy<int,1>;

    static_assert(exactly_one_not_0_v<multiple<d1>>);
    static_assert(exactly_one_not_0_v<multiple<d1,d0>>);
    static_assert(exactly_one_not_0_v<multiple<d0,d1>>);
    static_assert(exactly_one_not_0_v<multiple<d0,d1,d0>>);

    static_assert(!exactly_one_not_0_v<multiple<>>);
    static_assert(!exactly_one_not_0_v<multiple<d0>>);
    static_assert(!exactly_one_not_0_v<multiple<d0,d0>>);
    static_assert(!exactly_one_not_0_v<multiple<d1,d1>>);
    static_assert(!exactly_one_not_0_v<multiple<d0,d1,d1>>);
    static_assert(!exactly_one_not_0_v<multiple<d1,d0,d1>>);
    static_assert(!exactly_one_not_0_v<multiple<d1,d1,d0>>);
```

The first four asserts fail. Why? The specialization should be able to catch these cases.

In comparison the following code works as expected (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/871ee1cc28f5ddc9):

```
    #include <iostream>
    template<class T>
    struct multi_pack
    {
          static void f() {std::cout << "base case\n";}
    };

    template<class...Ts1, class...Ts2>
    struct multi_pack<std::pair<std::tuple<Ts1...>, std::tuple<Ts2...>>>
    {
        using T = std::pair<std::tuple<Ts1...>, std::tuple<Ts2...>>;
        static void f() {std::cout << "special case\n";}
    };
```

Any idea why the first example fails and the second works?

Comment: With `multiple<d0,d0>`, you would get ambiguous deduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case, you're asking the compiler to match the packs inside separate types (there's a a pair of a tuple of `Ts1` and a tuple of `Ts2`). That's definitely unambiguous.

In your first example, both packs are used in the same parameter pack, separated by a third type. I understand why you expect it to work, but apparently the compiler (both gcc and clang) refuses to match prefixed packs entirely.

In your particular case, it's actually ambiguous in several cases: since V is a parameter, it may as well be 0, making it ambiguous to match a sequence of `d0`. Anyway, I tried that even using a constant 1 doesn't solve the problem. You will have to strip the prefix yourself.

```
#include <type_traits>
template<class, int> struct dummy{};
template<class...> struct multiple{};

template<class T, class = void> // <-- was this supposed to be an enabler?
struct exactly_one_not_0 : std::false_type {};

template<class Ts, class...RTs, int V>
struct exactly_one_not_0
<
    multiple
    <
        dummy<Ts, V>,
        dummy<RTs, 0>...
    >,
    std::enable_if_t<V!=0>
> : std::bool_constant<V>
{};

template<class LT, class...RDummies>
struct exactly_one_not_0
<
    multiple
    <
        dummy<LT, 0>,
        RDummies...
    >
> : exactly_one_not_0<multiple<RDummies...>>
{};

template<class T>
constexpr bool exactly_one_not_0_v = exactly_one_not_0<T>::value;

using d0 = dummy<int,0>;
using d1 = dummy<int,1>;

static_assert(exactly_one_not_0_v<multiple<d1>>);
static_assert(exactly_one_not_0_v<multiple<d1,d0>>);
static_assert(exactly_one_not_0_v<multiple<d0,d1>>);
static_assert(exactly_one_not_0_v<multiple<d0,d1,d0>>);

static_assert(!exactly_one_not_0_v<multiple<>>);
static_assert(!exactly_one_not_0_v<multiple<d0>>);
static_assert(!exactly_one_not_0_v<multiple<d0,d0>>);
static_assert(!exactly_one_not_0_v<multiple<d1,d1>>);
static_assert(!exactly_one_not_0_v<multiple<d0,d1,d1>>);
static_assert(!exactly_one_not_0_v<multiple<d1,d0,d1>>);
static_assert(!exactly_one_not_0_v<multiple<d1,d1,d0>>);

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

For the sake of not instantiating multiple `multiple`s, you may want to strip that out as well

```
template<class T>
struct exactly_one_not_0 : std::false_type {};

template<class Enable, class... Ts> // <-- was this supposed to be an enabler?
struct exactly_one_not_0_impl : std::false_type {};

template<class... Ts>
struct exactly_one_not_0<multiple<Ts...>>
    : exactly_one_not_0_impl<void, Ts...>
{};

template<class Ts, class...RTs, int V>
struct exactly_one_not_0_impl
<
    std::enable_if_t<V!=0>,
    dummy<Ts, V>,
    dummy<RTs, 0>...
> : std::bool_constant<V>
{};

template<class LT, class...RDummies>
struct exactly_one_not_0_impl
<
    void,
    dummy<LT, 0>,
    RDummies...
> : exactly_one_not_0_impl<void, RDummies...>
{};
```

Comment: Yes, `template<class T, class = std::true_type>` was supposed to be an enable/disable switch (though I kind of messed it up by not using void and enable_if). I hoped I could prevent the recursive solution you posted. My main question was Why it is not matched (e.g.: is it a bug or something in the standard).

Comment: @wsxedcrfv sorry. I was just as lazy as you in not looking at the standard. I believe the offending clause is 17.5.5 - 8.4, which states "Within the argument list of a class template partial specialization, the following restrictions apply: [...]  If an argument is a pack expansion, it shall be the last argument in the template argument list.". I would interpret it to only apply to the first level of the argument list (i.e. not to your case), but it looks like I'm wrong.